# How to accelerate calculations when update messive position from 3d to screen (hud)

Tags: three.js, projection

I want to update hud positon form 3d position to 2d when mouse moving. Since it may have a large number of 3d objects to project to the screen position, I meet a performance problem.

Are there any way to accelerate calculations? The following is how I calculate 3d object position on 2d screen.

```
function toScreenPosition(obj) {
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
    //calculate screen half size
    var widthHalf = 0.5 * renderer.context.canvas.width;
    var heightHalf = 0.5 * renderer.context.canvas.height;
    //get 3d object position
    obj.updateMatrixWorld();
    vector.setFromMatrixPosition(obj.matrixWorld); 
    vector.project(this.camera);
    //get 2d position on screen
    vector.x = (vector.x * widthHalf) + widthHalf;
    vector.y = -(vector.y * heightHalf) + heightHalf;

    return {
        x: vector.x,
        y: vector.y
    };
}
```

Comment: Do not instantiate a new `THREE.Vector3` every time the function is called; create one and reuse it. Do not instantiate a new object when the function returns. Do not recompute `width/heighHalf` every call. And do not call `obj.updateMatrixWorld()` either. The renderer calls that for you every frame.

Comment: @WestLangley have you tested your solution?  i don't think that can solve my problem when it has over 100+ hud objects in scene to calculate position in 2d screen. since i am not using object3d right now, just calculate the center point of object3d as you said only Vector3.

Comment: What @WestLangley writes is almost universally true and will to some extent improve your performance. Might not be enough though. Another possible optimization is the `.project()`-call. This internally has to compute the matrixWorldInverse of the camera, which is a pretty expensive operation. You should consider to reimplement it in a way that caches the computation of the transform-matrix over the entire frame: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/ae2cda96f52b763b27b9c0cf77f1a9ed498fd706/src/math/Vector3.js#L318-L323 - you will be left with just a few computations which JS can handle well

Comment: @Leo.Lin My suggestions were not intended to be a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than repositioning your HUD in world space every time your camera moves, add your HUD object(s) to your camera object, and position them only once. Then, when your camera moves, your HUD moves along with it, because the camera's transformation is cascaded to it's children.

```
yourCamera.add(yourHUD);
yourHUD.position.z = 10;
```

Note that doing it this way (or even positioning it the way you were) may allow scene objects to clip through your HUD geometry, or even appear between your HUD and the camera, obscuring the HUD. If that's what you want, great! If not, you could move your HUD to a second render pass, allowing it to remain "on top."

Answer (score 1):

First, here is an example of your function rewritten for (almost) optimal performance as written in the comments above, the renderloop is obviously just an example to illustrate where to do which calls:

```
var width = renderer.context.canvas.width;
var height = renderer.context.canvas.height;

// has to be called whenever the canvas-size changes
function onCanvasResize() {
  width = renderer.context.canvas.width;
  height = renderer.context.canvas.height;
});

var projMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();

// renderloop-function, called per animation-frame
function render() {    
  // just needed once per frame (even better would be 
  // once per camera-movement)
  projMatrix.multiplyMatrices( 
    camera.projectionMatrix, 
    projMatrix.getInverse(camera.matrixWorld)
  );

  hudObjects.forEach(function(obj) {
    toScreenPosition(obj, projMatrix);
  });
}

// wrapped in IIFE to store the local vector-variable (this pattern 
// is used everywhere in three.js)
var toScreenPosition = (function() {
  var vector = new THREE.Vector3();

  return function __toScreenPosition(obj, projectionMatrix) {
    // this could potentially be left away, but isn't too
    // expensive as there are 'needsUpdate'-checks in place
    obj.updateMatrixWorld();
    vector.setFromMatrixPosition(obj.matrixWorld);
    vector.applyMatrix4(projectionMatrix);

    vector.x = (vector.x + 1) * width / 2;
    vector.y = (1 - vector.y) * height / 2;

    // might want to consider returning a Vector3-instance 
    // instead, depends on how the result is used
    return {x: vector.x, y: vector.y};
  }
}) ();
```

But, considering you want to render a HUD, it would be better to do that independently of the main-scene, making all of the above computations obsolete and also allowing you to choose a different coordinate-system for sizing and positioning of HUD-elements.

I have an example for this here: https://codepen.io/usefulthink/pen/ZKPvPB. There I used an orthographic camera and a seperate scene to render HUD-Elements on top of the 3d-scene. No extra computations required. Plus I can specify the size and position of HUD-elements conveniently in pixel-units (The same would work using a perspective camera, only requires a bit more trigonometry to get it right).

Comment: 100% agree with the second half of this answer. Manipulating HUD elements in the main scene will be expensive (as Leo has seen). Moving them to a secondary scene/render pass makes it a trivial matter.

Comment: actually i have 2 options for hud implication.1: to use another scene and orthographic camera.2 to use just another div on webgl canvas, and it works pretty good. the problem is not how to render the hud layer, the main problem is the calculation of each position. i will test your solution @Martin Schuhfuß, thx ahead!